# Can I render just one component in svelte so I can tweak my design?

Tags: html, rendering, svelte

If I've got a single component in svelte:

```html
<div>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

is there a way I can render *only* this component in the browser?

I want to be able to tweak the styling and layout of this component but without the whole rest of the website. I'm not sure where the component will go in the website just yet, so I don't have an easy place to put it, but it seems like svelte should be able to render just this one component without knowing how it fits into the bigger picture.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is stopping you?

Comment: I have the component at `src/lib/MyComponent.svelte`, but I can't go to `localhost:5173/src/lib/MyComponent.svelte` to see what it would look like because that's not a valid route. I don't see how I can get svelte to render a component at a specific address, but only during development.

Comment: https://storybook.js.org/

This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Can't you create some testing route and import only particular component?

Comment: I'm trying to migrate a project from react, so this would require creating ~50 routes just for testing. I was hoping I could just point svelte at a component and have it figure out the boilerplate for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here you go:

- Add an id to the `div` element: e.g. `id="#nice"`
- Run this script:

```js
function hideAllBut(selector) {
    let el = document.querySelector(selector)
    el.style.visibility = 'visible'
    el.style.position = 'fixed'
    el.style.top = 0
    el.style.bottom = 0
    el.style.left = 0
    el.style.right = 0

    while (el.parentElement) {
        el.parentElement.style.visibility = 'hidden'
        el = el.parentElement
    }
}

hideAllBut('#nice')
```